# Can essentially bounded function take infinite value on measure zero set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I know that $\|f\|_{\infty}=esssup_{x\in X}(f(x))$, which means we can neglect measure zero sets in our definition of essential supremum. 
I am comportable when the function is bounded on all points of the domain. 
But I wonder what if function takes some infinite value at some point $x\in X$;
i.e, $f(x)=\infty$.
Obviously, it is not bounded function, but is it essentially bounded?

Comment: Is a point a set of measure zero? Ergo?

Comment: Surely, point is measure zero.

Comment: Hence? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: That is the very question I am asking. Actually, I am studying some blow up properties of solutions of PDE. So if solution is essentially bounded, but if it lets to blow up on measure zero set.  The definition of blow up is some how questionable. I am confused.

Comment: Thus $L_{\infty}$ boundedness of PDE solution is still let's infinite value at some points.

Comment: If your PDE solutions are continuous, see last example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe some examples will help?

- Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=14$ if $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=42$, then $\|f\|_\infty=14$.
- Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=1/|x|$ if $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=42$, then $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$.
- Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=3$ if $x$ is not integer and $f(x)=42$ if $x$ is an integer, then $\|f\|_\infty=3$.
- Consider  $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ *continuous*. If  $\|f\|_\infty$ is finite, say  $\|f\|_\infty=M$, then $|f(x)|\leqslant M$ for *every* $x$ (that is, the set of measure zero in the definition of the essential supremum, is actually empty for continuous functions).

Comment: Did, in your first example why you think $\|f\|_\infty=1$.

Comment: +1 for the excellent examples. I know this is nitpicky and only correcting a typo, but just to make your answer perfect, shouldn't $\left\|f\right\|_{\infty}=3$ in the first example?

Comment: yeah, I think it is $\|f\|_{\infty}}=3$

Comment: @AmiteshDatta Typo (due to a lack of coffee, let's say). Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I accept function can take infinite value at measure zero set if it is essentially bounded. Now things are becoming more complicated.

Comment: Since $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the value $f(0)=+\infty$ is not admissible. It should be $f:\mathbb{R}\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis Thanks for your input. I modified the examples to get functions with values in $\mathbb R$.